# Find Command, I want to use my variables

Tags: scripting, ksh

I have a script that creates a new directory based on User Input, and well as which directory contents it will copy over.  Now here is where I am having issues, I have a find command that will replace files that have a specific name in front and replace it with the new name.  It works, but I want to use the variables that I've created instead of a changing the string I have set, I keep getting an error saying it can't do it.

```
#Creates Directory
echo "Name of New Directory"
read userInput
if [[ -n "$newdir" ]]
then
  mkdir $newdir
fi
echo $newdir Directory Created
echo 
echo "Directory you wish to Copy?"
read copydir
if [[ -n "$copydir" ]]
then
#Copies contents of Specified Directory
 cp -R $copydir/!(*.UNC) $newdir;

#Searches through directory  
find $newdir/ -name "$copydir*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; mv "$f" "${f/sppark/work}"' - {} \;


fi
```

So instead of sppark and work, I want to use my variables newdir and copydir, in the Find command.

Comment: Changed the Title, I require assistance with my Find command, I want to use my variables $newdir and $copydir, instead of "${f/sppark/work}", where newdir is work and copydir is sppark

Comment: you could use `rename` instead of `mv`..

Comment: That was my first guess, but `rename` doesn't exist in my environment, and I can't just download it, so `mv` is next best

Comment: Why ksh and exec bash ? Perhaps you can try to export your variables before calling find.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used a for loop and a mv instead to do what I want.

```
    #Searches through directory  
for file in $newdir/$copydir*; do
#Changes Part of File Name
mv -- "$file" "$(echo ${file}|sed 's/'$copydir'/'$newdir'/')"
done
```